# SOCKS5 proxy via UDP, unrechable packets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, proxy, udp

I trying to send UDP packets via SOCKS5 proxy server (random public server from search), but i getting this

[image: Wireshark capture]

Socks5 connection code (C#) [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f2jmyCN0).

I do the following:

- Create TCP connection to SOCKS5 and sending auth method.
- Sending UDP ASSOCIATE command from created TCP socket.
- Receiving SOCKS5 port (DST.PORT) of created proxy udp socket.
- Sending packet bytes with destination address and port.

Perhaps has misunderstood RFC1928, I'll appreciate any help.